# El usuario comunidad puede traducir preguntas?

Tags: discusión

Esta pregunta [PROBLEM WITH COLLATION (NULL) CREATING A DATABASE SQL SERVER](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226017/problem-with-collation-null-creating-a-database-sql-server) ha sido publicada y dentro de la zona de comentarios le he indicado que debe traducirla por encontrarse en la versión en español de SO; sin embargo noto que el usuario comunidad ya ha traducido el contenido.

Pregunto si esto es permitido por que hasta donde he visto no es bien recibido que alguien que no sea el OP lo haga.

En caso de que no sea correcto es bien visto si se revierte dicha edición?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si miras el enlace de la [edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/133443) verás que no fue Comunidad quién lo tradujo si no un usuario anónimo.

En realidad fue el mismo OP quien la tradujo pero sin haber accedido con su usuario.

Esa revisión, la aprobaron dos usuarios por lo que **Comunidad se *atribuye el mérito*** en estos casos

Comment: @shadow En este caso es válida porque la hizo el propio OP. Si no fuera él, no lo serían.